# Scope contains value, but when accessing it, it's undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an AngularJS directive, and when I try to access a scope variable, it's `undefined`. If I print out the `scope`, I can clearly see that the variable has a value.

Check your JavaScript console, that's where I'm print this stuff to.

Here's a Plunker thing: http://plnkr.co/edit/1cSVZJgtlUazOqTuCNOK

Comment: Setting `debugger;` breakpoints before each log call shows `scope.usernameAvailable` as undefined at all three stages.

Comment: The problem is that when you log a javascript object to console the data is only captured once you expand the object. Try `console.log(Object.assign({}, scope));` and you'll see that it's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `<form>` directive which provides the values for the `form` value has not been compiled yet when the `usernameAvailable` has been compiled, since it is clearly a child scope of `form`. The reason why you would see the `usernameAvaiable` value when using `console.log()` is because it prints the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects) of the `$scope` object (this means the latest value that it had). If you really want to access such value, a workaround would be to use [$timeout()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to access the value.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ahRHdBfttUq2j9kJtn7x?p=preview)**

```
app.directive('usernameAvailable', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      usernameAvailable: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, controller) {
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.usernameAvailable.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function(username) {
          if (typeof(getCurrentUsername) != 'undefined' && username == getCurrentUsername()) {
            return $q.resolve();
          } else {
            return $http.get('/user/usernameAvailable?username=' + username).success(function(result) {
              if (result) {
                return $q.resolve();
              } else {
                return $q.reject();
              }
            });
          }
        };  
      });

    }
  }
}]);
```